# Rational number with rational exponent becomes rational

Tags: rational-numbers

I'm looking for a proof to show when $p^q$ for $p,q \in \mathbb{Q}$ is again in $\mathbb{Q}$, without factoring. I'm not sure, if it's possible, given these two numbers to say if the result is again rational and if so, calculate the result efficiently as well.

Thanks!

Comment: If $q = \frac{m}{n}$ in lowest form, then $p$ must be an $n$-th power of some other rational number for $p^q$ to be rational.

Answer (score 5):

it is not correct for eg: 
$$
2\in \mathbb{Q},\frac{1}{2}\in \mathbb{Q}\;\;\;but :\sqrt{2}=2^{\frac{1}{2}}\notin \mathbb{Q}$$

Comment: Yes, I want to have a general proof without factorization.

Comment: i think taking eg is enough to show that it's not right

Comment: I don't want to show that the statement is true. The question is for what $p, q$ the statement holds.

Comment: If $x$ is rational, $p \in \mathbb Z$ and $0 \ne q \in \mathbb Z$, then $x^{\frac pq}$ is rational if and only if $x = y^q$ for some rational number $y$.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding slightly on Arthur's comment. Let $p,q\in \mathbb{Q}$ and let $p=\frac{r}{s}$ and $q=\frac{m}{n}$ where $\gcd(r,s)=1$ and $\gcd(m,n)=1$. Then $p^q\in \mathbb{Q}$ iff $\exists l,k\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $r=l^n$ and $s=k^n$.

I think this can be proved without resorting to using a prime number decomposition of $r,s$ just by using $\gcd$ but I will have to think about it for a little bit. It's certainly easier to prove using decomposition.